# Efficient way of calculating averages from 60 different dataframes?

Tags: pandas

**Problem:**
Calculating average of 60 dataframe takes more than 2 hours to calculate average whereas most of its time is to create dataframe (1 day = 1 bhav copy).

**My approach:**
I have approached by calculating averages of 3 months of bhavcopy data by create 60 dataframes where average of close value is calculated.

**Code:**

```
t_3month = (
    float(
        previous_loc['no_trades']
        .to_string(index=False)
        .replace('Series([], )', '1'))
    + float(
        day3_loc['no_trades']
        .to_string(index=False)
        .replace('Series([], )', '1'))
    + float(
        day4_loc['no_trades']
        .to_string(index=False)
        .replace('Series([], )', '1'))
    #
    # repeat adding float
    # from dataframes day5_loc to day67_loc
    #
    + float(
        day68_loc['no_trades']
        .to_string(index=False)
        .replace('Series([], )', '1'))
    + float(
        day69_loc['no_trades']
        .to_string(index=False)
        .replace('Series([], )', '1'))
    ) / 68
```

I need to reduce time taken by this process as there are 60+ dataframes  locating takes lot of time. Can you calculate average of 60 days data without creating dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

You can try instead of trying to calculate the average of one huge DataFrame, you can calculate the sum and amount of variables to sum for each dataframe and then sum them up and calculate directly
Use [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) and [count](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html).

Sine you are not creating anything new it should lower your run time.